# NSHTTPURLResponse is nil but no NSError is generated

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks, nsurlsession, nserror

I am trying to read the `NSHTTPURLResponse` status code, however the `NSHTTPURLResponse` is returning nil, but no `NSError` is created.

This **worked prior to iOS 11**, but I am getting no warnings that it is deprecated and I am unable to find anything online referencing `NSURLSession` with this issue.

***Any idea why?***

I generally call the below method `[MyClass getHTTPResponseRequest:@"http://www.google.com/"];`

```
+ (NSInteger) getHTTPResponseRequest : (NSString*) testURL {
    __block NSHTTPURLResponse * r = nil;

    [[[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:testURL]
                                 completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response,  NSError *error) {

                if (error) {
                     NSLog(@"Error %@", error.localizedDescription);
                }

                r = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)response;

    }] resume];

    if(r == nil){
        NSLog(@"Response is nil");
        return 9999;
    }

    return r.statusCode;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would not have worked prior to iOS 11 either. The `dataTaskWithURL` completion handler is called asynchronously, but you're not waiting for the request to finish before attempting to return the `statusCode`.

You should adopt an asynchronous pattern, e.g. use completion handler pattern yourself:

```
+ (void)getHTTPResponseRequestWithURL:(NSString *)urlString completion:(void(^ _Nonnull)(NSInteger))completion {
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

    [[[NSURLSession sharedSession] dataTaskWithURL:url completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response,  NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"Error %@", error.localizedDescription);
        }

        NSInteger statusCode;
        if ([response isKindOfClass:[NSHTTPURLResponse class]]) {
            statusCode = [(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response statusCode];
        } else {
            statusCode = 9999;
        }

        completion(statusCode);
    }] resume];
}
```

And you'd call it like:

```
[MyClass getHTTPResponseRequestWithURL:@"http://google.com" completion:^(NSInteger statusCode) {
    // examine the `statusCode` here

    NSLog(@"%ld", (long)statusCode);
}];

// but the above runs asynchronously, so you won't have `statusCode` here
```

Now, clearly your completion handler parameters are generally returning something more meaningful than just the integer `statusCode`, but it illustrates the idea: Don't try to return a value from an asynchronous method without employing an asynchronous pattern (such as the completion handler).

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate you taking time to help and show me a new pattern!